# What is the relationship between dopamine and mathematical ability (if any)?

Tags: dopamine

I am curious to know if there is any existing literature that suggests that an increase in dopamine lends itself to an increased interest in solving problems of a mathematical nature.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A study **[Evidence that methylphenidate enhances the saliency of a mathematical task by increasing dopamine in the human brain](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/15229048)** suggests that using of [Methylphenidate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Methylphenidate) that is prescribed for attention deficit hyperactivity disorder (ADHD) increases the performance in mathematical tasks in healthy subjects. Methylphenidate primarily acts as a [dopamine-norepinephrine reuptake inhibitor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norepinephrine-dopamine_reuptake_inhibitor).

> Methylphenidate, when coupled with the mathematical task,
>   significantly increased extracellular dopamine, but this did not occur
>   when coupled with the neutral task. The mathematical task did not
>   increase dopamine when coupled with placebo. Subjective reports about
>   interest and motivation in the mathematical task were greater with
>   methylphenidate than with placebo and were associated with dopamine
>   increases.

Comment: Interesting. Is this exclusive to methylphenidate? Or does it apply to other DRIs, such as lisdexamfetamine?